# Anchor podcast public api

Tags: react-native, express

Can I get the list of episodes of my anchor account in JS. Anchor give us embed code which is iframe.

Can I get the episode name with any public API?

My requirement is to show the list of all episodes of specific person on anchor platform on my mobile app.

Comment: I was looking for that and didn`t found. Read the RSS feed looks reasonable for you?

Comment: It appears there is an undocumented private API. Not sure this would help for your scenario, but did find an easy way to access a CSV with this data: https://anchor.fm/api/proxy/v3/analytics/station/webStationId:[your-station-id]/topEpisodes?limit=1000&timeRangeStart=1550102400&timeRangeEnd=1611187200&csvFilename=TopEpisodes.csv

Answer (score 4):

Podcasts are based on RSS feeds, so yes, you can get all the details of your podcast by loading and reading the RSS feed off any podcast.

The RSS URL of the Anchor podcasts is `https://anchor.fm/s/PODCAST_ID/podcast/rss` where `PODCAST_ID` is the ID of your podcast.

Comment: Get PODCAST_ID by url  https://anchor.fm/api/vanityslug?url=/your-podcast/

Answer (score 3):

Q: Can I get the episode name with any public API?

There is no Public API from Anchor I think... And I need also to create my own landing page for my Podcast on Anchor. Then I look up the source code in my anchor page and I saw the `window.__STATE__` variable in the source code.

Hmmm... It is very nice to me! With the `window.__STATE__` I can catch `json` value after using my dirty PHP Code. Just implements some built-in method PHP have:

- file_get_contents()
- substr()
- strpos()
- str_replace()

and additional method if you want to save `json` code in your internal file using:

- file_put_contents()

This is my dirty PHP code (but it's work nicely!)

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('https://anchor.fm/<your-podcast-page-name>');

$json = substr($html, strpos($html, 'window.__STATE__ = {') , strpos($html, '"isError":false}};') - (strpos($html, 'window.__STATE__ = {')-1));

$json = str_replace('window.__STATE__ = ', '', $json);

$json = str_replace('"isNewUser":false,"', '"isNewUser":false,"isError":false}}', $json);

file_put_contents('podcasts.json', $json);
```

Sorry for my bad English... Cheers!